# Can I make \directlua understand unicode chars like ≥, ≤, ≠, ∙, and −?

Tags: luatex, unicode, plain-tex, lua, directlua

MWE:

```
\directlua{%
  local abs=math.abs
  function gcd(x, y)
    if y \csstring\~= 0 then
      return gcd(y, x \csstring\% y)% I would like to write "≠" instead of "~=".
    else
      return abs(x)
    end
  end}

\directlua{tex.print(gcd(768,640))}% prints 128

\bye
```

Is there a way to write `≠` instead of `~=` (or `≥` instead of `>=` inside `directlua{...}`? This would improve the readability.

Thanks.

Comment: anything is possible but for someone who can read Lua (rather than read mathematics) I'm not sure it would help? (just replace directlua by a macro that does some lua pattern replace to replace the uniocde by legal lua syntax before passing to `\directlua`

Comment: What you ask for is preposterous.

Comment: If I run your example I get `(./aa035.tex[\directlua]:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'abs')`

Comment: @JairoA.delRio booo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
{
\endlinechar=-1
\catcode`\≠\active
\catcode`\%\active
\gdef\zzz{\bgroup
\catcode`\≠\active\edef≠{\string~=}
\catcode`\%\active\edef%{\string%}
\zzzz}
\gdef\zzzz#1{\directlua{#1}\egroup}
}

\zzz{
  local abs=math.abs
  function gcd(x, y)
    if y ≠ 0 then
      return gcd(y, x % y)
    else
      return abs(x)
    end
  end}

\directlua{tex.print(gcd(768,640))}% prints 128

\bye
```

Comment: +1 – Wow! But: why???

Comment: @DG' because I get 45 points closer to passing egreg?

Comment: Well, fair enough ;)

Comment: I have the impression this will break things somewhere else, but who am I to judge it?

Comment: @JairoA.delRio not really: the definitions of the symbols are local to the argument of `\zzz` (or course like any verb-like command you can't use this inside another command, but other than that it is safe enough)